# Picker automatically focusing in CarouselViewControl while scrolling items in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms, in Carousel View control i have product items and i have picker control for the quantity selection. but when scrolling item in the Carousel View. picker getting focus. What is the issue. I have no picker focus event or method in carousel item scrolling.

please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply york shen. I already got solution for that thanks.